# Round check marks in menu items (Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa

Win32 API allows to place check marks of 2 kinds near the menu item caption: V mark, circle mark.

In Cocoa API I see it's possible to use "V mark" in menu items. How to use "circle mark" too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the images for the possible menu item states (`NSControlStateValueOn`, `NSControlStateValueOff`, or `NSControlStateValueMixed`) by setting the image properties of the `NSMenuItem`: `onStateImage`, `offStateImage`, and `mixedStateImage`, respectively.

This will replace the checkmark image(s) in the menu item with whatever you want. You'll have to provide your own artwork.